# Have both a tor-less tor browser and a regular tor browser

Tags: configuration

I would like to use the Tor browser, without the Tor Proxy and at the same time, still being able to use the regular Tor browser, Tor Proxy included.

On both Ubuntu and Windows, I cannot run two instances of Tor. The "no multiple instances of Tor proxies at the same time rule" shouldn't (?) be relevant here.

Running the following command
`TOR_TRANSPROXY=1  TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1 ./start-tor-browser.desktop`
I can configure a Tor-less Tor browser. But I still need to do more steps (such as disabling network.proxy.socks_remote_dns , ...) and I would like to not to mess up my "regular Tor browser config" each time I want to connect to a Tor-hating website.

Having an easy way to toggle on and off such configuration would be great but I don't know how to do it.

Even better would be to :

- have a way to toggle that on and off
- AND being able to run the Tor browser and the Tor Browser + proxy at the same time.

Comment: Can you just have two separate copies of Tor Browser in two separate directories, one with Tor disabled and one with the default configuration? That way when you change the configuration of one, the other stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you just have two separate copies of Tor Browser in two separate directories, one with Tor disabled and one with the default configuration? That way when you change the configuration of one, the other stays the same.

I thought it wasn't possible at first because I couldn't launch 2 tor with different settings at the same time, even if I had one of them with the `TOR_TRANSPROXY=1  TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1`. However, the reason was a bit more complicated then that.

So I'll share everything I had to do here so if anyone wants to do the same.
(Works for both Windows and Linux[Ubuntu]) for Tor > 10.

- Have 2 separate folders with tor. One will be the regular Tor and will be kept untouched. The other one will be the tor browser without the Proxy.
- Go on the about:config tab in the browser and add the two following variables :
  `TOR_TRANSPROXY=1  TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1`
- Create a firefox.cfg file. There are converters on the internet changing txt files into cfg easely. The following settings reset themselves if one just change them in the about:config tab, so we will need to lock them explicitly.
- Write the following inside of the file :

```
//
lockPref(“network.proxy.type”, 0);
lockPref(“network.proxy.socks_remote_dns”, false);
lockPref(“extensions.torlauncher.start_tor”, false);
```

The first line must always be commented for technical reasons. The second line indicates that we will use no proxy. I tried a value of 4 on windows (auto detect proxy) and it worked. It didn't on ubuntu and thus had to use 0 instead. I didn't need to set the `extensions.torlauncher.start_tor` to false on windows for some reason, while I needed it on ubuntu.

- Put the file into the same folder where the tor executable is located.
- Then go into the > defaults > pref folders
- Create a file named : `local-settings.js`
- Paste the following into the file :
  `pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg");`
  Like that, we indicates to the browser that it needs to read and lock our preferences.
  To check if it worked, go into about:config and search for the aforementioned locked preferences. They should be grayed out and changed to the value we described above.

This should normally be enough to have a Tor browser without the proxy. Having two separate folders is enough to not change the configuration of the other browser. If everything worked correctly, then it should be possible to launch both this browser and a regular instance of Tor (proxy enabled).

I would link to the sources that helped me but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post links.